# Conntrack TCP Timeout for state stablished not working

Tags: networking, embedded, routing, nat

Im using a private IP address and I want to keep alive SNAT entries in my Router (Gateway) for at least two hours (some windows apps of my network are using TCP keepalive set to 2 hours). Gateway is a Linux machine so i set `nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established` and `nf_conntrack_generic_timeout` values to 7400 seconds:

```
echo 7400 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_established
echo 7400 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_generic_timeout
```

Now, when a TCP connection is stablished shortly after i can see the new value:

```
# cat /proc/net/ip_conntrack
tcp      6 7399 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.0.192 dst=108.168.176.194
sport=51826 dport=5222 src=108.168.176.194 dst=95.63.14.117 sport=5222 
dport=51826 [ASSURED] use=1
```

But few seconds later i read the value again and now the value has returned to 60 seconds:

```
tcp      6 39 ESTABLISHED src=192.168.0.192 dst=108.168.176.194 
sport=51826 dport=5222 src=108.168.176.194 dst=95.63.14.117 sport=5222 
dport=51826 [ASSURED] use=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause was that the conntrack code in the kernel has been modified. As we are using a embedded linux distribution modified by our provider, the function that refresh the timeout for the SNAT entry was pointing to a special function used for provide one of the our provider new 'features'. I have fixed it and now it is working as expected.